# How to un trim the date in vb6 (milliseconds must appear). The date is coming from stored procedure in sybase

Tags: vb6

I have a problem of passing a full datetime value from VB6 to sybase using ADO. It seems the milliseconds are left out.

Here's example code for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_ReturnDatetimeInput (
  @Input datetime, 
  @Output datetime output
)
AS
--Show input value
print '@Input = ' + convert(varchar(20), @Input, 14)
set @Output = @Input
GO
```

vb6 code

```
Private Function TestDatetimeOutputValue(dInput as Date) As Date
  Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
  With cmd
  <snip>
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Input", adDBTimeStamp, , 8, dInput)
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Output", adDBTimeStamp, adParamOutput, 8, dInput)
  .Execute

  If Not IsEmpty(.Parameters("@Output").Value) Then
    TestDatetimeOutputValue = .Parameters("@Output").Value
  End If
  End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `adDBTimeStamp` field is not a VB Date type.  By blithely assigning its value to a Date variable you have converted it, truncating it to fit.

See [How To Get Fractions of a Second from ADO adDBTimeStamp Field](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193869). <sup>[archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20070109175034/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193869)</sup>

You can choose how to carry such values to work with them in VB6.  One option might be a UDT with a Date field and a Long or Integer to hold the milliseconds.  Another might be to calculate something you store in a Decimal or Currency type variable, where you scale the Date value up to a whole part and add in the ms. as a fractional part for example.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 does not store milliseconds in the date data type.  So... the value you pass in to the procedure already has the milliseconds removed.